# Reasons for seeing an assembly push operand is the bottleneck

Tags: c++, c, assembly, cpu-registers, cpu-cache

I have a piece of code written in C and I want to find the bottleneck for this code! Using `perf` tool and annotating the assembly code, I see the `push %r12` instruction at the start of the function is being the bottleneck (see the picture):

[image]

I'm a bit confused with that! How a simple push instruction leads to be a bottleneck? Is it possible that CPU is forced to update the content on memory from cache before pushing the register content to the stack? If yes, I would appreciate if you let me know what is the reason behind that.

This is the input parameters for my function, in case it is required:

```
nt32_t
rte_hash_lookup(const struct rte_hash *h, const void *key)
{
    RETURN_IF_TRUE(((h == NULL) || (key == NULL)), -EINVAL);
    return __rte_hash_lookup_with_hash(h, key, rte_hash_hash(h, key), NULL);
}
```

Comment: The CPU can schedule a certain number of opcodes in parallel, it also has a certain number of writes to memory it can buffer. So it might be that it will always stall on the 4th push. Or the timer that increments the usage count just triggers in an unlucky pattern. Probably a combination of the two.

Comment: Could be that the something slow wrote `%r12` in the caller just before the function call, like a cache-miss load.  As the first instruction to read `%r12`, this push would get the blame.  (Or perhaps an eliminated `mov` from a `div` result?  Not sure if that would be possible.)

Comment: Thank you both for sharing your thoughts. I think it's more like @PeterCordes 's suggestion. After playing with different variables it seems that the ```push``` instruction is getting the blame without actually being the bottleneck. So far I know some cache-misses is happening but I should find the reason behind that.